# What is the best way to create xslt dynamically from xhtml?

Tags: asp.net, xslt, xhtml

I have a XHTML Template. I want to convert dynamically the xhtml file to xslt . Waht is the best way to do this?
Below written the XHTML content

```
<div>
{:header:}
<br />
{:date:}
<p>
{:mailingattn:} <br />
{:facilityname:} <br />
{:facilitystreet:} <br />
{:facilitystreet2:} <br />
{:facilitycity:}, {:facilitystate:}  {:facilityzip:} <br />
{:facilitycountry:}
</p>

<p>
{:message:}
</p>

<p>
Sincerely,<br />
{:signature:}
</p>
{:footer:}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know precisely the semantics of the macros used in your XHTML file, but the following transformation produces an XSLT stylesheet which is hopefully equivalent, and if not, should be easily tailored to your needs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="xsl:stylesheet">
            <xsl:attribute name="version" select="'2.0'"/>
            <xsl:element name="xsl:template">
                <xsl:attribute name="match" select="'/*'"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:variable name="regex">\{:([a-zA-Z0-9]*):\}</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$regex}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                    <xsl:attribute name="select" select="regex-group(1)"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.. Will you please tell how can I use this format to My template?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using XProc and <p:template> ?

http://www.w3.org/TR/xproc-template/#c.template